# Standard networks for different agent types

Tags: anylogic

The standard networks (small-world etc.) provided by Anylogic are sufficient for my model. However, when I create two different agent populations with different networks, they seem to be connected with the other agent type as well. For now, I would need two distinct agent types with two distinct networks.

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think they "seem to be" connected?

Comment: Because I have visualised the connections and also have a function that counts these connections... So I am sure that the different agent types are connected with each other. I just want to connect the agents within their specific agent type! :)